# How can I rewrite a Postgres request is C#?

Tags: c#, json, postgresql

How can I rewrite next PosgtreSQL request via C#? I need to get records in the response that store an empty json object in one of the columns.

```
select column from some_table
where   json_array_length(some_table.column::json->'items') = 0
```

I'm trying to do it by this way (schema code):

```
var neededColumn = Db.GetQuotedColumnName<neededTable>(m => m.column);
var object = nameof(neededTable.columm.object);

var select = request.emptyObject.Select(_ => $"{neededColumn}->>'{object}' = '[]'");
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You'll need to provide an example of the code you have written and have a specific question about.

Comment: You should be able to write raw query strings in your database client. What client are you using?

Comment: I'm using DBeaver